# Git clone from Sourceforge using Netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: git, netbeans, git-clone, sourceforge

This sounds silly. But, wanted to know anyway. I am trying to clone git repository from sourceforge using Netbeans 8. As per the project's sourceforge page, the git clone can be done with the following way

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode neembuuuploader-gitcode
```

The above link is mentioned [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode/ci/master/tree/).

Netbeans throwing error as it is not able to connect with the server. 
The master has folder as `modules` in it's root directory. I tried appending it with url and still the same issue.

[image]

I have not tried any other git cloning mechanism (like from terminal), since I need it from Netbeans only. I can understand that I am making mistake in the clone url.

What should be the correct form I have to use ?

Comment: Hmm I'm checking this out (no pun intended), and it's a NetBeans issue. Works fine in terminal... Trying to figure it out...

Comment: Hmmm I did what I could, but that's a strange error. Maybe submit a ticket?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the log from NetBeans:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.git]: git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode neembuuuploader-gitcode: not found.
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode neembuuuploader-gitcode: not found.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackConnection.noRepository(BasePackConnection.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackConnection.readAdvertisedRefsImpl(BasePackConnection.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackConnection.readAdvertisedRefs(BasePackConnection.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitAnon$TcpFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitAnon.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitAnon.openFetch(TransportGitAnon.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.ListRemoteObjectsCommand.runTransportCommand(ListRemoteObjectsCommand.java:74)
Caused: org.netbeans.libs.git.GitException: git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode neembuuuploader-gitcode: not found.
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.TransportCommand.handleException(TransportCommand.java:259)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.ListRemoteObjectsCommand.runTransportCommand(ListRemoteObjectsCommand.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.TransportCommand.run(TransportCommand.java:191)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:77)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand.execute(GitCommand.java:77)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.GitClient.listRemoteBranches(GitClient.java:861)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$35.call(GitClient.java:589)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$35.call(GitClient.java:585)
    at org.openide.util.NetworkSettings.suppressAuthenticationDialog(NetworkSettings.java:140)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1$1.call(GitClient.java:885)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1.call(GitClient.java:906)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethodIntern(GitClient.java:918)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:851)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:829)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.access$400(GitClient.java:823)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient.listRemoteBranches(GitClient.java:585)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.clone.RepositoryStep$RepositoryStepProgressSupport.perform(RepositoryStep.java:325)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.performIntern(GitProgressSupport.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.run(GitProgressSupport.java:107)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

I don't quite understand why it's not working. It works fine for other repositories. Maybe the space in the URL is throwing it off? Maybe it just doesn't like that server?

I just worked around it in command line:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode neembuuuploader-gitcode
```

---

I tried SVN too:

```
svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/code/ neembuuuploader-code'
```

That gave me this exception:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E170000: URL 'svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/code/%20neembuuuploader-code' non-existent in revision 705
```

I really don't understand why this error is occurring...

---

This is possibly an IDE bug. It might be worth submitting a bug report: https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: Sorry I can't help more :P

Answer (score 1):

```
git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode neembuuuploader-gitcode
```

are actually two parameters passed to git clone command in CLI, the first is
the repository URL, the second local folder on your hard drive where to clone
to.

We have to use just `git://git.code.sf.net/p/neembuuuploader/gitcode` into the
URL field in Netbeans.

Thanks to Ondrej Vrabec from NetBeans Dev team.

**Reference :**  https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252090